# Copy instance of class of package

Tags: python-2.7, copy, ubuntu-14.04, pycharm, ros

I work with the *rosbag* package which is provided by [ROS.org](http://www.ros.org). My code looks like

```
import rosbag

bag_path = "/path/to/bag/file.bag"
bag = rosbag.Bag(bat_path)
```

And what I want to do is, to copy the instance *bag* correctly, because I want to process the data in two different threads.

Unfortunatelly, the class *Bag* does not provide a proper function *copy()*.

So, how do I copy a instance of a external class properly?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) package can be used to create new and identical instances of custom classes.

```
import copy

class TestClass:
   def __init__(self, a, b, c):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       self.c = c

x = TestClass(1, 2, 3)
y = copy.copy(x)
```

`x` and `y` have exactly the save variable properties, but if you change `x.a`, `y.a` will not be affected.

Comment: Thank you! Excactly what I wanted to have!